# Need help to find maximum of this summation equation

Tags: probability, derivatives

I tried to solve [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) myself,  and  I found its bruteforce equation. I am proud that I understood what it is and I can also solve its variations by changing equation. However I don't have a formal mathematics education, and I don't know how to find maximum of this equation.

$$ \frac{x! \cdot (n-x)! }{ n! } \sum_{k=1}^{n-x} (1/k) \cdot \binom{n-1-k}{x-1} $$

maximum of this equation occurs when x is n/e, I verified it by putting it on wolfram alpha and toying with variables.

Now can you help me find maximum of this equation. Aside from solution, you can also recommend me a good book that I can study myself.

: I am adding what this formula is and what it means as suggested. This formula gives the probability of finding best choice if one rejects first x applicants and after that, choosing first applicant that has a higher score than all previously encountered ones.

How I constructed the formula : lets say there are total n= 100 numbers (applicants). and whatever x is; if 100 is after first x that you reject all of them, and 99 is among first x; you will definitely choose best.

we can choose (x-1) applicants - because 99 is among them- from 98 applicants. for the first x. we can rearrange them x! different ways and (n-x)! different arrangements for the remaining part. n! are all possible arrangements and dividing it gives probability.

and if 100 and 99 are after x; but 98 is in first x; now we can choose x-1 numbers from 97 different numbers. but this time because 99 and 100 are after x, the probability of encountering 100 before 99 is 1/2

and likewise if 98 99 and 100 are after x, the probability decreases with 1/3 and it goes on like this. everything is just basic logic to be honest.

Comment: From what I remember, you can imitate the procedure for maximizing a differentiable (continuous) function by looking at the difference quotients of consecutive terms.  You should be able to show this discrete distribution is *unimodal*, that is, it has one peak.

Comment: My math isnt enough to do that. I have to study. But I study a lot to be honest, i give myself. so If you can recommend me a book, i can study

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point would be for you to add an explanation of what the formula above *represents*, i.e. is it the probability of something?  What do variables $x$ and $n$ stand for?  This will give Readers a better idea of your thinking.

Comment: ok i am adding, to be honest i dont think it will be any help to find maximum, but maybe it helps

Comment: You could start to look at Fellers classic Theory f probability, volume 1.!